# Is it possible to draw an image or text on a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Is it possible to draw on a `JFrame` without adding a `JPanel` to it?

i override `paintComponents()` but it didn't show anything.

```
 @Override
public void paintComponents(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponents(g);
    g.drawString("for test", 10, 10);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is.  You'll want to work with the one of the panes in the JFrame such as the content pane or the [glass pane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html#glasspane), which you can access via [getContentPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#getContentPane%28%29), etc.

For example the content pane is a [Container](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html), with a variety of add methods.  To that you can add any [Component](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html) - doesn't have to be a JPanel specifically.  More at [Using Top Level Containers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html).

Usually, though, drawing is done via overriding paint (for AWT) or paintComponent (for Swing).  This means you need some sort of Component or [JComponent](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html) that you put in your frame.  More at the [2D Graphics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) tutorial.  Why do you not want to change that?

You can also override JFrame and its content pane and have a content pane with an override paintComponent method.

I question, however, the necessity and wisdom of directly drawing on a JFrame.

Comment: jframe have **paintComponents** no **paintComponent**

Comment: @mehdi - I see that looking through the API.  You can override the content pane, which does have paintComponent.

Comment: @mehdi JFrame !is-a JComponent, JFrame is-a Frame :-)

Comment: how can i override content pane?

Comment: @medhi - override JFrame and in the constructor set up the content pane via `setContentPane` as some JComponent child you have created yourself with paintComponent overriden.  But at that point, what is the specific reason for not just adding a component via `JFrame.getContentPane().add()`?  Or outside your JFrame, use `JFrame.setContentPane()` and set it to your own JComponent.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anybody still insists of painting on the top-level Window directly (which is *not* recommended), here's how (because the [code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134840/drawing-on-jframe) linked to in the other answer is simply wrong)

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("funny ...") {

       @Override
       public void paint(Graphics g) {
           super.paint(g);
           g.drawString("for test", 150, 150);
       }

    };
    frame.getRootPane().setOpaque(false);
    ((JComponent) frame.getContentPane()).setOpaque(false);
```

Obviously, to make it shine-through all the way up, everything above (in Z-order) has to be not-opaque.

Cheers
Jeanette

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be possible. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134840/drawing-on-jframe) previous SO post to see how it can be done.

Answer (score 2):

JFrames have a GlassPane on top of them, which can be used for graphics. [Here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html#glasspane) you have a simple example that shows how to use it.