# How could I implement a render() method into my JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to create a little graphical game that has both a text and graphical version. For both versions I used a render() method which draws everything to the board (in this case, would draw it to the JFrame). However, I'm having trouble trying to add the method to the JFrame. I was wondering how to do this and if I can't what else I could do.

```
// Rows
    for (int x = 0; x < this.cells.length; x++) {

        // Columns
        for (int y = 0; y < this.cells[x].length; y++) {
            if (this.cells[x][y].type == Cell.EMPTY) {
                g.setColor(Color.black);
                g.drawOval(x, y, 10, 10);
            } else if (this.cells[x][y].type == Cell.MONSTER) {
                g.setColor(Color.red);
                Polygon poly = new Polygon();
                poly.addPoint(x, y);
                poly.addPoint(x - 10, y - 10);
                poly.addPoint(x + 10, y + 10);
                g.drawPolygon(poly);

            }
```

This is the render method which searches through the array of cells and based on the type of object at its x and y, will draw the according shape. Though, i'm relatively new to the programming world, i'd appreciate all the help I can get!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134840/drawing-on-jframe

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't draw to the frame.  Instead, draw to a `JPanel`.
2. To do custom painting, `@Override` the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method.

   - be sure to first call `super.paintComponent(g);` before rendering.
3. Also `@Override` the preferred size of the panel to return a dimension that will show the entire drawing.
4. Implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks (e.g. to animate)

   - In the listener, adjust positions or other factors related to rendering, then call `repaint();`.