# Create multiple of 1 objects next to each other (grid like)

Tags: java

Hey if i have a simple rectangle class, how can i make it so that it creates that rectangle next to each other in a grid like pattern? maybe like 10 rows 10 columns?

```
public class Vak {

private int posX = 0;
private int posY = 0;
private int width = 50;
private int height = 50;
private Color colour;


public Vak(Color c, int x, int y){
    this.colour = c;
    this.posX = x;
    this.posY = y;

}

public int vakPosY(){
    return this.posY;
}
public int vakPosX(){
    return this.posX;
}

public void draw (Graphics g){
    g.setColor(this.colour);

    g.drawRect(posX, posY, width, height);
}

public void move(int numberPixelsX, int numberPixelsY){
    this.posX = this.posX + numberPixelsX;
    this.posY = this.posY + numberPixelsY;
}
```

}

this is my code for rectangle "vak"

Comment: Are you looking for a multidimensional array? Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067073/initialising-a-multidimensional-array-in-java

Comment: @kevcodez, he might be looking for a for loop.

Comment: user1806846, Is this for a tile-based game?

Comment: @АндрейБеньковский yes it is for a tile based game.

Comment: @АндрейБеньковский okay i did!

Comment: @user1806846 And where are you going to get the colors of tiles from? From a file? Generate randomly? Use a chess pattern? Or are you going to fill them with one color for now?

Comment: @user1806846 Why do you want the tiles to be able to move with pixel precision? Can tile width and height change while the game runs?

Comment: @АндрейБеньковский that move operation isnt used, its from an older version. i dont want it to have any color yet, just the outline is enough (or an lightgrey or something) in the jframe file i create a new object where i use the constructer

Comment: your code looks good, you need to call `draw(g); move(10,20);` in a loop

Comment: ps: 10,20 is example. you need to calculate correct shifting values

Comment: @Yazan do u mean in a paint method in the jframe file? but that wont do anything

Comment: well, it was long ago since i played with paint() and Graphics, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134840/drawing-on-jframe, and why don't you consider using JButtons? in a GridLayout https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html ?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
int mapWidth = 10;
int mapHeight = 10;
// tileWidth and tileHeight should probably be public static const fields or static readonly properties of some class, but I put them here for now.
int tileWidth = 50;  // Pixels
int tileHeight = 50;  // Pixels
// tiles should probably be a field of a Map class (if you have one)
Vak[][] tiles = new Vak[mapWidth][mapHeight];
for(int x = 0; x < mapWidth; x++)
{
    for(int y = 0; y < mapHeight; y++)
    {
        tiles[x][y] = new Vak(Color.white, x*tileWidth, y*tileHeight);
    }
}
```

And then in the drawing part of the main loop:

```
for(Vak[] row : tiles)
{
    for(Vak tile : row)
    {
        tile.draw(g);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this! helped alot, but the objects now arent aligned good, i want all the square to be visible, the one on the top and left right arent completely visible now, how to fix that?

Comment: @user1806846 could you upload a screenshot illustrating your issue?

Comment: you need to make sure draw area (width & height) >= total tiles width and height.